# The specified table does not exist. [ __MigrationHistory ]

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, sql-server-ce, entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

I've been using the following method since Entity Framework Code First became available:

```
public virtual void CreateDatabase()
{
    var dbContext = _dbContextLocator.Current;
    dbContext.Database.Delete();
    dbContext.Database.Create();
    dbContext.Database.Initialize(true);
}
```

Recently, I noticed that when `dbContext.Database.Create()` is hit, I get the following exception:

> System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException occurred
>   Message=The specified table does not exist. [ __MigrationHistory ]
>   Source=SQL Server Compact ADO.NET Data Provider
>   ErrorCode=-2147467259
>   HResult=-2147217865
>   NativeError=0
>   StackTrace: at System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand.ProcessResults(Int32 hr)
>   InnerException:

If I go to Debug - Exceptions and check Thrown for "Common Language Runtime Exceptions", this causes execution to stop, and I get the above exception. If I uncheck it, the database seems to get created properly, but I get four repeats of the following error statements in my Output window:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeException' occurred in System.Data.SqlServerCe.Entity.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll
>   A first chance exception of type 'System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll

Placing a try/catch block around `dbContext.Database.Create()` has no effect.

My goal is to create a completely blank database, then fill it with data manually. I do not wish to use the new Migrations feature of Entity Framework.

What can I do to eliminate the first chance exceptions?

Comment: I noticed you're using compact edition - did you check to ensure that the DB has the _MigrationHistory table?  I do see it's trying to drop the table, but even it's recently dropped the database, you might run into some oddities - I recently documented my experiences with the _MigrationHistory table disappearing in CE.  It also shows the executed sql, and how I was able to get it working again [on this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11672812/code-first-migrations-and-initialization-error/11908847#11908847)

Comment: Im not too sure what database.delete does with CE, you might want to check that its actually working at all, does the file get deleted?

Comment: @LukeMcGregor, good question, but I just checked, and it definitely does delete the database.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> My goal is to create a completely blank database

Assume you mean a database with the actual schema objects required by your model?

If so, you have two options:

1) Ignore the exceptions - With SqlCE, EF uses the Migrations pipeline internally when creating databases. The exceptions are an implementation detail of how Migrations determines existence of the __MigrationHistory table.

2) Use the legacy APIs - The database creation APIs on ObjectContext use the legacy, non-migrations code path. Cast your DbContext to IObjectContextAdapter to obtain an ObjectContext reference.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, Andrew. +1. Do you think this can be considered a bug in Entity Framework? It seems like errors should not be generated when creating a new database.

Comment: No, this is just a somewhat unfortunate side-effect of how we determine existence of the history table. As you have observed, we are catching and swallowing these exceptions.